# Django i18n: how to translate None when rendering a model field in template?

Tags: django, django-models, localization, internationalization, django-i18n

I have this code:

```
# models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    end_date = models.DateField(verbose_name=_('end_date_field'), null=True, blank=True)
    notes = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('notes_field')), null=True, blank=True)

# template
<span>{{ object.end_date }}</span>
<span>{{ object.notes }}</span>

# settings.py
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pl'
```

If `end_date` or `notes` is NULL in the database, it displays as "None" in the template. How do I provide one-off, "global" translation for a `None` value?

I don't want to manually wrap every occurence of every nullable field across all templates.

Comment: You should use the `|default:"some string"` filter. You can't translate None. Use `{% trans "No date provided" as default_date %} {{ object.end_date|default:default_date }}`.

Comment: Also, for `TextField`, don't use `null=True` (only `blank=True`). See [this explanation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.null) why it's a bad idea to use `null=True` on a `TextField`.